# Tab and newline in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Here I am having two files (file1, file2) which contain ab and cd in row format, like below

**file1**

```
a
b
```

**file2**

```
c
d
```

Now, I have to create a script which finds the files and reads line by line and inserts into another file called Main. Output should be like below.

**Main**

```
a tab b
C tab d
```

Like matrix format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### paste

`paste` with `-s` option can do the job:

```
paste -s f1 f2
```

#### awk

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",FNR==1?"":"\t",$0}ENDFILE{print ""}' f1 f2
```

tested with GNU Awk 4.2.1

awk lets you do more control on the text.

Comment: @RaviKiranMekala you are welcome. accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Kent, if we have number of files then how to use paste command.? Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through it. But there is no option for n number of files. Until unless there is naming convention like file1 file2 file3 ...filen.                                                           for that, paste -s " " file{1..n}

Comment: can you give it a try? adding a new file after my `paste` line?

Comment: i am not getting what you are trying to say. But i was trying to make it like this.                    Paste -s * >> output  But it is not working though.

Comment: Anyway i have using this. it is working just fine for me. Thank you for you support.                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                           
for i in *
do
paste -s $i >> output
done

Comment: Make sure you *accept* a solution that works for you, especially after getting specific feedback from the answer poster. (Click the check mark.)